# Customizing MFC ribbon controls with dynamic linking

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon

I have a VS2017 MFC C++ application which uses a ribbon based UI.  Up until now I have been using the statically linked MFC libraries but now have to move to MFC in a DLL as I need *Multithreaded DLL linkage /MD* in order to support another third party SDK (Vulkan).  One of the reasons for using statically linked MFC is that it allowed me overcome some problems in the implementation simply by including the source for the item I needed to change in my application.  e.g. to use data the edit part of a combo box to select the nearest item in the drop down.  This doesn't work when I use the DLL version of MFC for obvious reasons, is there any way around this?  I can't simply inherit from MFC base classes as my application is building the ribbon interface from a ribbon resource file and there don't seem to be any hooks to customise this behaviour.

My current thoughts for possibilities include building my own version of the MFC DLLs or simply adding the full MFC source as a sub-project and change my main project *Use of MFC* to *Use Standard Windows Libraries*.  Both of these seem like nasty hacks.

**Edit:** In response to the comment below from IInspectable, I'm not entirely sure why the current behaviour doesn't work but have some ideas.  Linking the static lib version of the code, if I include my own copy of a function that occurs in the lib, the lib version never gets called (possibly never even gets linked).  When linking the DLL version of MFC, my modified function never gets called.  This could be because it is called by another function in the same DLL which never sees my code or it has a slightly different [decorated name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=msvc-170).  My thinking is that including all the MFC source in my app and not linking any MFC in the compiler options is one brute force solution, though a pretty horrible one.

Comment: *"This doesn't work when I use the DLL version of MFC for obvious reasons"* - Could you provide details on this? I'm not exactly fluent in Ribbon UI, nor which implementations need to be shared in this context, or how. Still, this all sounds like a problem that has a clean, robust solution. Can you clue me in?

Comment: @IInspectable, edited question with my thoughts on the matter but not entirely sure why this happens

Comment: I was rather interested in hearing about the concrete problem. If you wind up with *"slightly different decorated names"* then I'm pretty sure there's something else wrong (probably incompatible compiler settings).

Comment: @IInspectable, the problem I didn't actually know what was causing the unwanted behaviour.  The idea that it related to different decorated names was speculation, which at this point I suspect was wrong.  The solution I arrived at works well to circumvent the problem but doesn't actually establish the cause.

Comment: The workaround is not a solution. You cannot compile MFC from source without causing *very* subtle issues. And you'll lose all pretty much all error diagnostic information, unless you're willing to add the multi-GB PDBs to your source control.

Comment: Could you give examples of the type of issue you're referring to here?  I consider this is a solution in that it solves the very specific problem raised where I couldn't find any alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up recompiling a custom version of the MFC DLL based on this project, https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5263509/Compile-MFC-Sources-with-Visual-Studio-2019  This lets me keep my MFC modifications while also using MFC in a DLL with minimal changes to my existing project